# SparkSQL. Large amount of data saved to global temp view

Tags: apache-spark-sql, global-temp-tables

I am saving my data to global temp view, to keep it between the spark jobs.
I am wondering if there are performance issues regarding huge amounts? Does global view suffers it?

Comment: What is large? New session or not?

Comment: Same session... Aprox  3.2 million